# What's the preferred J source code file extension?

Tags: file, j

For the [J programming language](http://www.jsoftware.com/), I'd guess `.j`, but I've also seen `.ijs` and `.ijt`. Is it one of these, or even something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `.ijs` is the extension  for script files.
- `.ijt` indicates a special script used for labs.
- `.ijx` is used as the extension for session logs (not really used in J7).
- `.ijp` is used for project files in J6
- `.jproj` is used for project files in J7

Comment: Don't forget .ijp for projects :)

Comment: ijs - "Interpreted J Script"?

Answer (score 3):

From the example scripts from [JWiki](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Scripts), `.ijs` seems to be predominant.